# Can you have more than 1 submit button on each page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, exec

How to Format

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links

```
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

► basic HTML also allowed

formatting help »
asking help »

Comment: check form action for both `submit button`

Comment: You cannot submit two form at a time.But you can have multiple form(submit button) one page

Comment: Unrelated: I do hope that the actual script uses some sort of input validation. Otherwise it's open to SQL injection.

Comment: Invalid HTML: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" class="form-inline"/>`. There should not be a closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

It should work on HTML side. Maybe there is a PHP error.

Please insert behind

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
```

This code

```
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
```

Now click the second button and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Must have unique `name` attribute ie:

```
<input type="submit" name="button_1" value="button_1 clicked">
<input type="submit" name="button_2" value="button_2 clicked">
```

hence `button_1` and `button_2` are 2 different submit.

If you read GET/POST data, the button that was clicked will show

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure,
You just need to label it with "id" or "class" or "name".

e.g:

```
<button type="submit" id="buttonA">click me A!</button>

<button type="submit" id="buttonB">click me B!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple forms with submit button on same page. In your case you have 2 forms with different action. You need to check this

```
<form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php" class="form-inline">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" class="form-inline"/>
```

form action should be same if php code is written on same page.